# What is the simplest URL shortener application one could write in python for the Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Services like bit.ly are great for shortening URL’s that you want to include in tweets and other conversations. What is the simplest URL shortener application one could write in python for the Google App Engine?

Comment: I could write an incredibly short one, as long as you only needed to shorten 256 URLs.

Comment: Do you want your code to use an existing service or shorten the url itself?

Comment: I began thinking about the question after seeing a similar demo for another language.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That sounds like a challenge!

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import run_wsgi_app

class ShortLink(db.Model):
  url = db.TextProperty(required=True)

class CreateLinkHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    link = ShortLink(url=self.request.POST['url'])
    link.put()
    self.response.out.write("%s/%d" % (self.request.host_url, link.key().id())

  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('<form method="post" action="/create"><input type="text" name="url"><input type="submit"></form>')

class VisitLinkHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, id):
    link = ShortLink.get_by_id(int(id))
    if not link:
      self.error(404)
    else:
      self.redirect(link.url)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/create', CreateLinkHandler),
    ('/(\d+)', VisitLinkHandler),
])

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: @trusktr I wouldn't actually put up something this simple (or recommend anyone else do) - it's likely to be prone to abuse, since it has nothing to protect against abuse by spammers etc.

Answer (score 2):

similar, complete with GAE project boilerplate: https://github.com/dustingetz/vanity-redirect

Answer (score 1):

There is a django app on github, github.com/nileshk/url-shortener. I forked it to make it more of an all encompassing site,http://github.com/voidfiles/url-shortener.